# simple-snack-bar problem with rapid identification of messages that appear for a few seconds

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with the rapid identification of messages that appear for a few seconds. The code is below, but that is appear only max. 4 second and disappears.

```
<simple-snack-bar class="mat-simple-snackbar ng-star-inserted">
<span>The person was selected.</span><!---->
<div class="mat-simple-snackbar-action ng-star-inserted"><button mat-button="" class="mat-button">
<span class="mat-button-wrapper">Close</span>
```

I tried found it by selenium webdriver and python:

```
findelement = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('mat-simple-snackbar ng-star-inserted')
```

but nothing. Is it at all possible for selenium webdriver to process and find this in the test?

Answer (score 1):

`*_by_class_name` just for single class name, instead you can use `*_by_css_selector`.

```
findelements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.mat-simple-snackbar.ng-star-inserted')
```